# Cannot assign because it is borrowed the temporary

Tags: rust, ref, borrow-checker

I have the following code with two almost identical functions. One of them does not compile.

```
struct Node {
    pub data: i32,
    pub next: Option<Rc<RefCell<Node>>>,
    pub prev: Option<Weak<RefCell<Node>>>
}

impl Node {
    pub fn new(data: i32) -> Rc<RefCell<Self>> {
        Rc::new(RefCell::new(Self {
            data,
            next: None,
            prev: None
        }))
    }
}


fn print_iterate_doesnt_work(node: &Rc<RefCell<Node>>) {
    let mut current_node = node.clone();
    loop {
        current_node = {
            let current_node_ref = current_node.borrow();
            print!("{} ", current_node_ref.data);
            if current_node_ref.next.is_none() { 
                return; 
            }

            // This line doesn't work
            current_node.borrow().next.as_ref().unwrap().clone() 
        }
    }
}

fn print_iterate_works(node: &Rc<RefCell<Node>>) {
    let mut current_node = node.clone();
    loop {
        current_node = {
            let current_node_ref = current_node.borrow();
            print!("{} ", current_node_ref.data);
            if current_node_ref.next.is_none() { 
                return; 
            }

            // This one works
            current_node_ref.next.as_ref().unwrap().clone()
        }
    }
}
```

As I understand `current_node.borrow()` creates temporary `Ref`. Why doesn't compiler see that i don't use `current_node` and the temporary `Ref`. It says:

```
cannot assign to `current_node` because it is borrowed
the temporary is part of an expression at the end of a block;
consider forcing this temporary to be dropped sooner, before the block's local variables are dropped
borrow occurs due to deref coercion to `RefCell<Node>`rustcClick for full compiler diagnostic
main.rs(44, 13): `current_node` is borrowed here

main.rs(44, 13): a temporary with access to the borrow is created here ...

main.rs(46, 5): ... and the borrow might be used here, when that temporary is dropped 
and runs the destructor for type `Ref<'_, Node>`

rc.rs(1564, 5): deref defined here

main.rs(44, 13): for example, you could save the expression's value in a new local variable `x` 
and then make `x` be the expression at the end of the block: `let x = `, `; x`
```

I actually don't fully understand `... and the borrow might be used here, when that temporary is dropped  and runs the destructor for type 'Ref<'_, Node>'`

As a result I don't understand why should I `save the expression's value in a new local variable 'x'  and then make 'x' be the expression at the end of the block: 'let x = ', '; x'`

Cargo check:

```
error[E0506]: cannot assign to `current_node` because it is borrowed
    --> src\main.rs:39:9
     |
39   |         current_node = {
     |         ^^^^^^^^^^^^ `current_node` is assigned to here but it was already borrowed
...
45   |             current_node.borrow().next.as_ref().unwrap().clone() //
     |             ---------------------
     |             |
     |             `current_node` is borrowed here
     |             a temporary with access to the borrow is created here ...
46   |         }
47   |     }
     |     - ... and the borrow might be used here, when that temporary is dropped and runs the 
destructor for type `Ref<'_, Node>`
     |
     = note: the temporary is part of an expression at the end of a block;
             consider forcing this temporary to be dropped sooner, before the block's local variables are dropped
     = note: borrow occurs due to deref coercion to `RefCell<Node>`
```

So what's going on here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your non working version is equivalent to this:

```rust
fn print_iterate_doesnt_work(node: &Rc<RefCell<Node>>) {
    let mut current_node = node.clone();
    loop {
        let current_node_ref = current_node.borrow();
        print!("{} ", current_node_ref.data);
        if current_node_ref.next.is_none() { 
            return; 
        }
        
        current_node = current_node.borrow().next.as_ref().unwrap().clone();  
    }
}
```

Now the problem is that the temporary `current_node.borrow()` isn't dropped until the end of the statement. But at that time `current_node` has already been replaced.

The working example works, because it stores the temporary in a block scoped variable, which is dropped before returning from the block, so also before reassigning `current_node` so everything works out.